# Add a picker view at the footer of the app

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, datepicker, xcode6

I would like to add a picker view at the footer of the app when I tap the cell and change the Detail label with the picker view data. I would like to do the same think with the DatePicker, but only in one cell ( the one named Service appt. Date).

This is my code:

```
import UIKit

class Service2Appointment: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
@IBOutlet weak var TableView: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!

let FormName = ["State","City","Vehicle Reg Number","Location","Current Kms","Service appt. Date","Service appt. Type","Pick-up Vehicle","Discount Code","Service Notes"]

let textCellIdentifier = "TextCell"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    pickerView.hidden = true
    TableView.delegate = self
    TableView.dataSource = self
    self.TableView.rowHeight = 70
    TableView.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "background.png"))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK:  UITextFieldDelegate Methods
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return FormName.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   var cell = TableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(FormName[indexPath.row], forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    
    if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }else{
       
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        cell.textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.0)
    }
    
    let row = indexPath.row
    
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = FormName[row]
    
    cell.textLabel?.text = FormName[row]
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    return cell
}
// MARK:  UITableViewDelegate Methods
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        TableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        
        let row = indexPath.row
        println(FormName[row])
    }
}
```